# Is there any way why salesforce would pass incorrect id to the url (sent through email)?

Tags: salesforce-id

We have 2 different orgs with no installed packages shared.

These orgs have formulas: `"https://someurl.com?id="&Id`. On the first org the field is on standard Opportunity sObject and on the second one - on the custom object.

The link in both orgs is passed through emails. Less than 1% of the links are corrupted (3-4 out of 20k+).

Somehow when you click on the link (which look normal in salesforce) on our url shortener service it comes corrupted, for example:

Was: a044J00000QRiLeQAL Became: b377W33333DEIbmDBU (the first id is just an example, it wasn't converted to the second one, we don't know the initial id)

Was: 006************ Became: 3398a33333BGwxe (same here, we don't know the initial id, it's however some Opportunity record id)

I have noticed that the digits are always increased by 3. However, I didn't get how non-numeric symbols are changed. We don't know the initial ids, because there are too many records in both orgs of those types.

**Can you please direct me where to start searching?** Why the problem may even occur? There is definitely no such ids in salesforce, also, the last 3 chars in 18-chars ids are not representing the first 15, therefore, I am sure these ids cannot be produced explicitly by salesforce. **Probably, some email boxes has built-in encryption (I understand it sounds foolish, but I'm desperate)?**

Comment: This is likely on the receiver side. Log the email you send to verify that the link is correct.

Comment: The problem is that those orgs are clients'. The one with custom objects even use some package that create mailing campaigns, not standard email templates. I'll try to search in the other one for Email messages objects, propably, it will light up something for us. Thank you for the direction!